# How do I override a 3rd party's target="_parent" to be target="_self"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

**My Problem:**
On TypeForms I have 4 forms setup in a redirect chain

Form #1 → Form #2 → Form #3 → Form #4 → Form #1

The coding on their end that I don't have access too is set to target="_parent" for the redirect links. The first form starts off in a popup/modal as desired but when the "next" button is clicked at the end of form #1 to go to form #2 it refreshes my browser window to form #2 instead of staying within its original frame. I would like to know how I can override their code in order to keep all the forms loading within the original popup/modal.

In case you're wondering why I would set it up this way, to begin with. TypeForms doesn't allow multiple scores on a form, and my form is a psychological test that has 4 subscales. I had to design the forms in a way that would make it seem as if it was a single form on the user's end.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
<div <class="col sqs-col-12 span-3">
<div class="sqs-block button-block sqs-block-button" data-block-type="53" id="block-yui_3_17_2_20_1499707405549_16977">
    <div class="sqs-block-content">
        <div class="sqs-block-button-container--center" data-alignment="center" data-button-size="small">
            <a class="typeform-share button" href="https://granitemountain.typeform.com/to/b7rnDa" 
                data-mode="drawer_right" data-hide-headers=true data-hide-footer=true target="_blank">Launch Shame/Guilt Scale</a>
                <script> (function() { var qs,js,q,s,d=document, gi=d.getElementById, ce=d.createElement, gt=d.getElementsByTagName,
                    id="typef_orm_share", b="https://embed.typeform.com/"; if(!gi.call(d,id)){ js=ce.call(d,"script"); js.id=id; 
                    js.src=b+"embed.js"; q=gt.call(d,"script")[0]; q.parentNode.insertBefore(js,q) } })()
                </script>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to modify the behavior of a 3rd party website you have iframed in your own site?  If so, that's not possible (unless the third party sets up CORS access for you to do so.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by:

1. Removing the redirects that were embedded on TypeForms platforms.
2. Embedding the forms without links on separate pages.
3. Created my own links in their place so everything is on the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

this can redirect to same page

```
   <a href="open.html" target="_self">link.html</a>
```

Comment: I've tried replacing the "_blank" in my code with "_self" but that didn't do anything. What I've discovered is that on TypeForms side they have the code written as "_parent". When I contacted them to see if they could switch it I was told they couldn't. What I need to figure out now is how do I override their "_parent" to act as "_self" instead?